# How to show X amount of child divs on page load using JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a bunch of divs sat within a parent div with the structure like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4"></div>
    <div id="div5"></div>
    <div id="div6"></div>
    <div id="div7"></div>
    <div id="div8"></div>
    <div id="div9"></div>
    <div id="div10"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can control the number of child divs displayed on page load using JS or jQuery. I want to ideally just display the first 5 and set the rest of the child divs to

```
.css('display', 'none')
```

How can this be done?

Comment: next time please share code you have tried out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:gt()` selector that select elements with index great than special number.

```js
$("#container div:gt(4)").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
  <div id="div4">div4</div>
  <div id="div5">div5</div>
  <div id="div6">div6</div>
  <div id="div7">div7</div>
  <div id="div8">div8</div>
  <div id="div9">div9</div>
  <div id="div10">div10</div>
</div>
```

Also you can use pure javascript to do this work.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#container div").forEach(function(ele, i){
  i > 4 ? ele.style.display = "none" : '';
})
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#container div").forEach(function(ele, i){
  i > 4 ? ele.style.display = "none" : '';
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
  <div id="div4">div4</div>
  <div id="div5">div5</div>
  <div id="div6">div6</div>
  <div id="div7">div7</div>
  <div id="div8">div8</div>
  <div id="div9">div9</div>
  <div id="div10">div10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot - Keeping the code to a bare minimum. Works great thank you, will mark as correct when stack lets me.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without JS and instead using CSS's [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector:

```css
#container div:nth-child(n+6) { /* upto but not including 6th child */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
    <div id="div4">4</div>
    <div id="div5">5</div>
    <div id="div6">6</div>
    <div id="div7">7</div>
    <div id="div8">8</div>
    <div id="div9">9</div>
    <div id="div10">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look on the each function of jquery

```
let x = 5;
$(`#container`).find('div').each((index, element) => {
  // typeof index = number
  // typeof element = HTMLElement (not JQuery)
  if(index > x){
    $(element).css('display', 'none');
    // $(element).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: this removes elements instead of setting `diplsay: none`.

Comment: Correct, though the jQuery function `hide()` does the same thing and is better for readability in my opinion.

Comment: @MarkBaijens another option is to hide it via class and use addclass, 100 ways and none is wrong

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works but Mohammad answered first and his solution worked too so I have to mark him as accepted. I will upvote though.. thank you!

Comment: @mtizziani True, wasn't meant to offend you. Just a tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can add css for those div to be hidden on page load .

```js
let x = 5;
$("#container div:lt("+x+")").css('display','none') // on load
$("#show").on("click",function(){
 $("#container div:lt("+x+")").css('display','block');
 $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
    <div id="div4">4</div>
    <div id="div5">5</div>
    <div id="div6">6</div>
    <div id="div7">7</div>
    <div id="div8">8</div>
    <div id="div9">9</div>
    <div id="div10">10</div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="show now" id="show" />
```

Comment: Apologies - The div names were used purely for example. The names will never stay the same they are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need JS/jQuery for this. Simple CSS `nth-child` will work. But if you want, you can combine it with JS code, that is - set it dynamically. I'm not sure what's your goal for later, but simply "selecting" and hiding all elements after fifth with pure CSS looks like this:

```
#container div:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}
```